# Representing real function as integral over trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, mathematical-physics

Since one can clearly express any function $g(x)$ as
$$\int_0^{\infty} A(k)\cos(kx)dk+\int_0^{\infty} B(k)\sin(kx)dk,$$
how would $G(k)$ relate to $A(k)$ and $B(k)$? In other words, what would how would we express $G(k)$ in terms of $A(k)$ and $G(k)$ in terms of $B(k)$ where $G(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $g(x)$?

Comment: Please note that not every real function has a Fourier transform. Far from it, actually. But for those functions that do have it, are you asking how to express that transform in terms of the original function?

Comment: Yes. Given a function where its fourier transform exists, I'm wondering how it can be separated into the above two integrals of sine and cosine, and how G(k) can be written in terms of A(k). And similarly how G(k) can be written in terms of B(k).

Comment: Look for "inverse Fourier transform", and if you get it in terms of complex exponentials, separate it into real and imaginary parts using $\exp(it) = \cos(it)+i\sin(it)$ as usual.

Comment: How exactly would I compute G(k) in terms of A(k) and B(k) after using inverse fourier transform and using that? I already tried it out.